# Can we give Dashboard create/edit Permission to one User in a profile?

Tags: dashboard

I need to give Dashboard create/edit Permission to one User in a profile .

Comment: You want to give this permission to only one user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give the Dashboard create/edit Permission at profile level, its applicable for all users who are assigned to that respective profile.

If you want to give access to only one user then create a `permission set` and assign it the respective user.

Refer the [Create Permission Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_sets_create.htm&type=5)